# Simple "find element in array and return value" function in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a value like this:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

I need to compare this value to an array which converts this value into another value.

For example, if id==14, then check array for element 14, and return its value, for example in this case "Cars".

Anybody know a simple code for this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe:

```
$val = $arr[$_GET['id']];
```

Comment: `$_GET` will return it as a string, that might be problematic if it's numerically indexed. `$val = $arr[(int) $_GET['id']];`

Comment: @Core that is not an issue. `$arr[1]` is the same as `$arr['1']` because you cannot have `array('1' => 'foo', 1 => 'bar')`. The second will overwrite the first.

Comment: @Gordon: Ok. I like to be explicit about it myself, don't like the implicit conversions in PHP... Like how `"0"` evaluates lazily to `NULL`.

Comment: @Core help me for a second please. Under what situations would `"0"` become `NULL`. `var_dump( NULL == "0");` is `FALSE`.

Comment: @Gordin: Ah, sorry, I meant `false`. Comes up often parsing text and form input, where `"0"` evaluates to `false`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$array = array(
  "Books",
  "Furniture",
  .... // 11 more
  "Cars"
 );

 // Remove if indexes already start at 0
 $index = $_GET["id"] - 1; 

 if (array_key_exists($index, $array))
 echo $array[$index];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [`array_key_exists`](http://php.net/array_key_exists):

```
if (array_key_exists($id, $array)) {
    var_dump($array[$id]);
}
```

You could also use `isset($array[$id])` but it will return *false* if `$array[$id] === null`.

Comment: `if (isset($array[$id])) { var_dump($array[$id]); }`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I entirely follow what you want to do here are some possible solutions:

```
$_GET['id'] = '14';
```

```
$ary_of_stuff = array(
1=>'Bike',
2=>'Tricycle',
14=>'Car',
20=>'Plane'
);
$id=$_GET['id'];
$value = $ary_of_stuff[$id];

//$value = 'Car';
```

```
$id=$_GET['id'];
switch($id){
case 1:
case 2:
   $value='Bike';
   break;
case 14:
   $value='Car';
   break;
}

//$value = 'Car';
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the question is vague in regard to what element 14 means, e.g.

```
$dataArray = range(1,20);
echo $dataArray[14]; // 15
```

returns the element with the numeric index 14. Since the array returned by `range()` is zero-based, it is the 15th element. But when I remove the first element

```
unset($dataArray[0]);
echo $dataArray[14]; // 15
```

it is still returning 15 although it is now the really the 14th element. This is because an index does not denote position in the array. I could `shuffle` the array and index 14 could end up at first position. Or the array could contain associative keys, e.g.

```
$dataArray = array('foo' => 'bar', 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15);
echo $dataArray[14]; // 15
```

and 14 would still return 15. If your `$id` corresponds to the index number, the solutions given in the various answers so far solve your problem.

If you mean the position of the element in the array, you have to use an `ArrayIterator` to `seek` to the (zero-based) position:

```
$iterator = new ArrayIterator($dataArray);
$iterator->seek(13); // zero-based so 13 is the 14th element
echo $iterator->current(); // 13
```

or the regular array functions

```
reset($dataArray);
for($i=1; $i<14;$i++) next($dataArray);
echo current($dataArray); // 13
```

or somewhat shorter

```
echo current(array_slice($dataArray, 13, 0)); // 13
```

because

```
Pos Index Value
 0: [foo] => bar
 1: [0] => 1
 2: [1] => 2
 3: [2] => 3
 4: [3] => 4
 5: [4] => 5
 6: [5] => 6
 7: [6] => 7
 8: [7] => 8
 9: [8] => 9
10: [9] => 10
11: [10] => 11
12: [11] => 12
13: [12] => 13
14: [13] => 14
15: [14] => 15
```